# simple select returns unexpected result

Tags: php, sql-server, linux, pdo, odbc

running this code returns unexpected result

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
try{
    $pdo = new PDO('odbc:Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=192.168.178.11;Database=test;','sa', 'secret');
    $s = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM test');
    if($s->execute()){
        var_dump($s->fetchAll());
    }
    $s = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM test WHERE id = ?');
    if($s->execute(array(1))){
        var_dump($s->fetchAll());
    }
}catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e->xdebug_message;
}
```

returns

```
array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'id' => '1',
      0 => '1',
      'test' => 'test      ',
      1 => 'test      ',
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'id' => '2',
      0 => '2',
      'test' => 'test2     ',
      1 => 'test2     ',
    ),
    2 => 
    array (
      'id' => '3',
      0 => '3',
      'test' => 't3        ',
      1 => 't3        ',
    ),
)
```

as you can see the second statement fails

(note i'm running gentoo linux 64, and i'm connecting to SQL server 2012 on a win7 64 virtual machine)

Comment: are you getting any error message?

Comment: it appears to be a bug with the unix ODBC driver for SQL Server Solved for now

Answer (score 1):

I get the second statement using MySQL. You may need to free up the connection to the server between statements using [**closecursor**](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.closecursor.php) using SQL Server.

```
$pdo = new PDO('odbc:Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=192.168.178.11;Database=test;','sa', 'secret');
    $s = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM test');
    if($s->execute()){
        var_dump($s->fetch());
    }
    $s->closeCursor();// ADD THIS for SQL Server
    $s = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM test WHERE id = ?');
    if($s->execute(array(1))){
        var_dump($s->fetch());
```

PS `fetch()` only fetches 1 row. You should only have 1 id in `var_dump()`

Comment: jah i changed it later to fetchAll(question updated),
did not work doh:(

Comment: Did you try adding `closeCursor()` between statements. As I said in Answer I get the same `var_dump()` results with MySQL without `closeCursor()`. Using `fetchAll()` or `fetch()` should both produce results.

Comment: @borrel Tried query with `fetchAll()`.Both statements produce desired results.